# Need help figuring out a loop to shorten the length of some code

Tags: python, loops

I am running a linear regression model in python. A part of my code uses the code referenced below. I have about 30 of these iterations; each representing a independent variable or column from the sourced file.

I am trying to shorten it so that I can consolidate my code. Does anyone have any clue how to run this sort of thing in the loop?

The 'ABC' 'DEF' 'GHI' could be put into a list of some sort (there would be more of them in my code) and then cycled through that list. Or that would be ideal.

```
xlist = []; xlist2 = []
###################################################
if x1.value == False:
    pass
else:
    x1 = 'ABC'
    xlist.append(x1)
    xlist2.append(x1)
###################################################    
if x2.value == False:
    pass
else:
    x2 = 'DEF'
    xlist.append(x2)
    xlist2.append(x2)
###################################################
if x3.value == False:
    pass
else:
    x3 = 'GHI'
    xlist.append(x3)
    xlist2.append(x3)
###################################################
```

Comment: Can you share how your input looks like, especially x1, x2 and x3 variables?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that x1, x2, and x3 already exist (as in the question):

```
xlist1 = []
xlist2 = []

items = [(x1, 'ABC'), (x2, 'DEF'), (x3, 'GHI')]
for x, val in items:
    if x.value:
        xlist1.append(val)
        xlist2.append(val)
```

The key is to somehow associate the values `x1` and `'ABC'`; `x2` and `'DEF'`; and `x3` and `'GHI'`.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I was doing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the setup you could do something like this:

```
xvalues={'x2': 'DEF'}
values = ['ABC' ,'DEF', 'GHI' ]
items = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3' ]
for x in items:
  if xvalues.get(x) == None: 
    xvalues.update({x: values.pop()}) 
  else:
    values.pop()

In [214]: xvalues                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[214]: {'x2': 'DEF', 'x1': 'GHI', 'x3': 'ABC'}
```

If you can add the data format to you question, i can update this answer, but i hope this helps

Or to only insert values with a value, you can use this:

```
xinsert = [] 
xinsert2 = [] 
def makereduce(agg, rval): 
   if agg[1][rval]: 
     xinsert.append(rval) 
     xinsert2.append(rval) 
   return('',values)  

values={'x1': 'ABC', 'x2': 'DEF', 'x3': 'GHI', 'x4': None}    
reduce(makereduce, values, ('',values)) 

In [413]: xinsert                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[413]: ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
```